# Tomcat 7: wrong realm being used?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

Could anyone help me diagnose this issue?

In server.xml, I have two realms defined

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>
  <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" deployIgnore="^welcome.*">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm" failureCount="3" lockOutTime="3600">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" driverName="org.postgresql.Driver" connectionURL="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tomcat" connectionName="tomcat" connectionPassword="xxxxx" userTable="users" userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="user_pass" userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role_name"/>
    </Realm>
  </Host>
</Engine>
```

I'm expecting the JDBCRealm to take precedence over the UserDatabaseRealm.
However, a web application, with a directory directly inside webapps, with no META-INF/context.xml file is authenticating against the UserDatabaseRealm.

The relevant section of that application's WEB-INF/web.xml looks like this:

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>public</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/public/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>My Realm</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>test_role</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/public/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/public/login-failed.xhtml</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

The JDBCRealm does work for particular applications if I declare it in that application's META-INF/context.xml

Is something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but my tomcat installation is now working as I'd expect, with regards as to which realm each web application uses.

For what its worth, the only thing I did differently was to was to edit the project locally in eclipse & re-upload the war. Previously, I'd been editing in situ on the Tomcat server & then restarting the service.

I'm assuming that all Tomcat's configuration is reloaded from scratch on
a service restart, so I don't know why I saw the previous behaviour.